# Link to= not working with /route:parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have react router setup with route parameters `:name`

```
  <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact={true} component={Index} />
        <Route path="/about/:name" component={About} />
        <Route component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
  </Router>
```

Using `<Link to=`, links from Index correctly route to eg `/about/vinnie`.

However, if the `<Link to=` component is on the About page, clicking the link merely updates the browser URL, but dies not re-render the correct page.

Any clues why this might be happening?

About.jsx

```
render () {

    const id = this.props.match.params.name;

    return (
      <div className="Explore">
        <div className="container">

          <Api endpoint={[this._apiEndpoint(id, 'info')]} loadData={true}>
             <CustomerInfo />
          </Api>
...
```

Api.jsx

```
 render () {
    let showData = this.props.loadData ? null : <button onClick={() => this._loadButton()}>Show</button>;
    return (
      <span>
        {this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
          apiData: this.state.rawData
        })}
        {showData}
      </span>
    );
```

};

CustomerInfo.jsx

```
class CustomerInfo extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      CustomerInfo: {}
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.apiData !== nextProps.apiData) {
      this.setState({CustomerInfo: nextProps.apiData[0]});
    }
  }

  render() {
...
```

Comment: can you share the `About` component?

Comment: @QoP I added more detail to the example. Could it be because I'm using `componentWillReceiveProps` to update the CustomerInfo state?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the `exact` prop to your first `<Route />`.  Otherwise your routes match Index and About and I think react-router intentionally renders both.

Comment: I do have the exact tag, that is not the issue